# Как скриптом вырезать блок и вставить в другое место при определенной ширине экрана?

Tags: jquery

Есть следующая конструкция:

```css
.omega {color:red;}
#md{line-height:8px;}
```

```html
<div id="md">
<div class="unknown"> <p>Различные блоки</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>содержащие все что угодно</p></div>
<div class="alfa"> <a class="ml" href="#">ALFA - блок который нужно переместить</a></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>И снова различные блоки</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>содержащие</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>все что угодно</p></div>
<div class="omega"> <p>OMEGA - блок после которого нужно вставить</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>И снова различные блоки</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>содержащие</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>все что угодно</p></div>
</div>
```

Требуется с помощью jquery найти на странице блок с классом "alfa" вырезать его, далее найти блок с классом "omega" и вставить после него блок "alfa", но сделать это при условии, что ширина экрана не более 980px (если больше, то все остается как есть, если меньше, то вырезать и вставить).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать в виде скрипта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так, только при ресайзе обратно в широкую версию он не вернется.

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
  if ($(window).width() <= 980) {
    $('#md .alfa').insertAfter('#md .omega');
  }
});
```

```css
.omega {color:red;}
#md{line-height:8px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="md">
<div class="unknown"> <p>Различные блоки</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>содержащие все что угодно</p></div>
<div class="alfa"> <a class="ml" href="#">ALFA - блок который нужно переместить</a></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>И снова различные блоки</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>содержащие</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>все что угодно</p></div>
<div class="omega"> <p>OMEGA - блок после которого нужно вставить</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>И снова различные блоки</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>содержащие</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>все что угодно</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, то что нужно! Все работает как и хотелось! Обратно в широкую я думаю и не надо, это надо для тех кто зашел на сайт с моб. устройств с разрешением ниже 980.. Замечательное решение и всего в пару строк! У перемещаемого блока и оформление и скрипты которые его обрабатывают - все работает без изменений. Часто при адаптивной верстке второстепенные блоки занимающие много места, хочется убрать пониже или внутрь каких то блоков (у моб. версии сайта), css в этих случаях бессилен, а  с помощью php сильно сложно, сейчас буду знать как это сделать минимальными усилиями. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/rFhgQ/5/) в примере всё работает

```js
<div class='unknown'> <p>содержащие все что угодно</p></div><div class='unknown'> <p>И снова различные блоки</p></div><div class='unknown'> <p>содержащие</p></div><div class='unknown'> <p>все что угодно</p></div><div class='omega'> <p>OMEGA - блок после которого нужно вставить</p></div><div class='alfa'> <a class='ml' href='#'>ALFA - блок который нужно переместить</a></div><div class='unknown'> <p>И снова различные блоки</p></div><div class='unknown'> <p>содержащие</p></div><div class='unknown'> <p>все что угодно</p></div>" );
    } else {
        $( "#md" ).html( "<div class='unknown'> <p>Различные блоки</p></div><div class='unknown'> <p>содержащие все что угодно</p></div><div class='alfa'> <a class='ml' href='#'>ALFA - блок который нужно переместить</a></div><div class='unknown'> <p>И снова различные блоки</p></div><div class='unknown'> <p>содержащие</p></div><div class='unknown'> <p>все что угодно</p></div><div class='omega'> <p>OMEGA - блок после которого нужно вставить</p></div><div class='unknown'> <p>И снова различные блоки</p></div><div class='unknown'> <p>содержащие</p></div><div class='unknown'> <p>все что угодно</p></div>" );
    }
}
$(window).load(windowSize); // при загрузке
$(window).resize(windowSize); // при изменении размеров
// или "два-в-одном", вместо двух последних строк
$(window).on('load resize',windowSize);
```

```css
.omega {color:red;}
#md{line-height:8px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="md">
<div class="unknown"> <p>Различные блоки</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>содержащие все что угодно</p></div>
<div class="alfa"> <a class="ml" href="#">ALFA - блок который нужно переместить</a></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>И снова различные блоки</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>содержащие</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>все что угодно</p></div>
<div class="omega"> <p>OMEGA - блок после которого нужно вставить</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>И снова различные блоки</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>содержащие</p></div>
<div class="unknown"> <p>все что угодно</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но если делать так как у вас скрипте нужно знать содержимое страницы (блока #md), а содержимое неизвестно (на всех страницах по разному) + количество блоков которые указаны в вопросе с классом "unknown" настолько много, что даже если бы они были известны, все их прописать в скрипте просто нереально - нужно более изящное/универсальное решение